# Excel VBA Autofilter keep deleting data that are not match with the criteria

Tags: vba, excel

*EDIT
I've tried my code with a new excel file, and it worked! but when I tried it with my current file, the same thing happened. 
*EDIT

I have a code here that will filter the data based on the criteria "NO". The code will filter the data from sheet5 and copy them to sheet1. My problem here is, the code will automatically delete the data with criteria other than "NO" in the master sheet (sheet5). I want the data in the master sheet to stay untouched. Any helps are much appreciated.

```
Sub searchX()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet5") 'master
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'reminder

With ws1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B3").AutoFilter
    .Range("B3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="NO",
On Error Resume Next  
.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B15")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

MsgBox ("Search done.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried with your code, and I dont think its deleting any data while running the code. It simply copies the filtered data to other sheet. It works fine for me.also you need to remove comma at end of this following line,.Range("B3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="NO",

Comment: Hi, @Durgaprasad I tried again, now it wont worked at all, and all the data in the master sheet vanished.

Comment: The code you are showing can't delete the data, unless you have your worksheets swapped. You might want to provide your two worksheets with an example of what you expect your code to accomplish.

Comment: hi @GMalc thank you for your input. I already solved the issue. I am not sure what is wrong, but when I use the same code in new excel file, new worksheet, it worked. So I just decide to abandon my previous excel file.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes to your code, I removed `.Range("B3").AutoFilter`, it works, but it may not work the way you want it to.

```
Sub searchX()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5") 'master
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'reminder

With ws1
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("B3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="NO"
    On Error Resume Next
    .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B15")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

MsgBox ("Search done.")
End Sub
```

Comment: The code does exactly what you describe; it filters the worksheet, and then copies the visible cells and paste them starting at `Range("B15")` on the destination worksheet.